# Creating and storing a varying number of shapes in an arraylist in javafx

Tags: java, class, arraylist, javafx, instance

I have been messing around with javafx for practice and ran across something I couldn't figure out. I want to put a varying number of rectangles into an arraylist. Right now, instead of that, I am storing each rectangle as an double array (double[]) of the various properties, then setting a base rectangle to those values and returning that.

```
public class example{
    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,25,25);
    ArrayList<double[]> rectangles = new ArrayList();
    double[] tempArray = [0,0];
    public void addRect (double x, double y){
        this.tempArray[0] = x;
        this.tempArray[1] = y;
        this.rectangles.add(this.tempArray);
    };
    public Rectangle getRect (int id){
        this.myRectangle.setX(this.rectangles.get(id)[0]);
        this.myRectangle.setY(this.rectangles.get(id)[1]);
        return(this.rectangle);
    };
}
```

In this example, when I call getRect, it sets the x and y of the base rect, then returns that rect. This works, but I am wondering if there is a way to store multiple instances of Rectangle in the ArrayList. The main issue I saw doing this is the fact that you have to name the instance(in the example above, myRectangle). I imagine that if there is a way around this issue, it would be to name the instance based on a string, in other words:

```
Rectangle "myRectangle" = new Rectangle();
```

which is not possible, as far as I know.

I am fairly new to Javafx and Java in general so if there is anything else off with my code feel free to correct that. Thanks!

Comment: "The main issue I saw is that you have to name the instance". Why do you think you have to name the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make an `ArrayList<Rectangle>` and add rectangles to it.

```
public class Example {
    private List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        rectangles.add(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle(int index) {
        return rectangles.get(index);
    }
}
```

You should note that your original code really doesn't work as expected at all. For example, try:

```
// please do NOT name classes with lower case...
example e = new example();
e.addRectangle(0, 0);
e.addRectangle(100, 100);

Rectangle rect1 = e.getRectangle(0);
System.out.println("Rectangle 1: ["+rect1.getX()+", "+rect1.getY()+"]");
Rectangle rect2 = e.getRectangle(1);
System.out.println("Rectangle 2: ["+rect2.getX()+", "+rect2.getY()+"]");

// but:
System.out.println("Rectangle 1: ["+rect1.getX()+", "+rect1.getY()+"]");
// oops.

System.out.println("Rectangle 1 and 2 are the same: " + (rect1==rect2) );
```

Comment: Thanks! I was only aware of using this: Rectangle ______ = new Rectangle();